# Why a subclass is instance of object?

Tags: python, instance, subclass

As I know, subclass should be subclass of `object`, but why it also is an instance of `object`?

```
hmank ~ » python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 26 2019, 21:43:19) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...   pass
... 
>>> isinstance(A, object)
True
>>> issubclass(A, object)
True
>>>
```

What's more, I quote from @prosti answer that `isinstance`

> [Returns a Boolean stating whether the object is an instance or subclass of another object](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html).

But the examples on the same link shows

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> isinstance(Bar, Foo)
False
>
```

Seems it means a **class1** is an instance of **class2**, if and only if **class2** is `object`, right?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, post code as *formatted text*. Anyway, **every** object is an instance of `object` in python.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I think it is faster to check the code if you have it as text.

Comment: THANKS for the suggestion that DO NOT upload images. And use formatted text now.

Comment: I dropped few more lines @roachsinai

Comment: @prosti thanks a lot!

Comment: @roachsinai No problem. Glad you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bad question.

```
class A:
  pass

a = A()

print(isinstance(a, A)) #True
print(isinstance(object, A)) #False
print(isinstance(A, object)) #True
print(issubclass(A, A)) #True
print(issubclass(A, object)) #True
```

By definition, [`isinstance`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html):

> Returns a Boolean stating whether the object is an instance or subclass of another object.

On the other hand [`issubclass`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/issubclass.html):

> Returns a Bool type indicating whether an object is a subclass of a class.

With additional remark that a class is considered a *subclass* of itself.

---

**Update:**

> Seems it means a class1 is an instance of class2, if and only if class2 is object, right?

You get answers by testing, and logic is super simple. A class is a class and object is an instance of a class.

You can check the code in case you really need to understand the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a24107b04c1277e3c1105f98aff5bfa3a98b33a0/Objects/abstract.c#L2364).

Also you may find the [test cases](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/test/test_isinstance.py) if you are a geek.

The object must be instantiated in order to classify for `True` in the following examples:

```
class Foo: pass
class Bar(Foo): pass
print(isinstance(Bar(), Foo)) #True
print(isinstance(Bar(), Bar)) #True

print(Bar) #<class '__main__.Bar'>
print(Bar()) #<__main__.Bar object at 0x7f9fc8f32828>
```

Also, some examples in here are Python3 specific, if you are Python2 guy, you must know that you should be more explicit and write:

```
class Bar(object): pass
```

The `(object)` part is a must if you write Python agnostic code.
Lastly check [Standard on Overloading isinstance() and issubclass()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) but have in mind standards are "live" and may update in the future.

Lastly you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) on classes objects relation.

Comment: So, why `isinstance` support to check whether the object is subclass of another object? I mean there is some overlap between `issubclass`.

Comment: And the example at the link you post seems support that `isinstance(A, object)` is `True` only when the class parameter is `object`. https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html#example-2

Answer (score 1):

In python3 all classes derive from `object` thus

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

and

```
class A:
    pass
```

are identical.
Regarding why `isinstance(A, object)` returns `True`
see the following code

```
class A: 
    @classmethod 
    def do(cls): 
        print(f"hello from {cls.__name__}") 

A.do()                                                                  

# hello from A
```

Comment: It's not asking why `A` is derived from object. It's asking why the class itself is an instance of object.

Comment: a class definition is an object as it can have class methods and properties disregarding of whether it has been instantiated.

Comment: That would have been more like an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Because everything in python is treated as an object, which is a nicer way to say, every object is an instance of object in python!

If you think about it, it makes total sence,since python is an object oriented language, and because of that, it is be normal and expected that every value is an object

```
In [9]: class A: 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:                                                                                                                                               

In [10]: isinstance(A, object)                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: True

In [11]: isinstance(A(), object)                                                                                                                      
Out[11]: True

In [12]: isinstance(1, object)                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: True

In [13]: isinstance([2,3], object)                                                                                                                    
Out[13]: True

In [14]: isinstance('hello', object)                                                                                                                  
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: I think it would be more properly stated as: every object is an instance of a **class**.

Comment: @martineau but for my question is why a **class** is an instance of **object**.

Comment: @roachsinai: Because in Python, classes are objects, too. They're instances of [Metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

Comment: @martineau Yeah, classes are instances of Metaclass. But **object** is also an instance of Metaclass. The Metaclass means **type**. So why classes is also an instance of **object**?

Comment: @roachsinai: Because, almost mystically, here's some circular logic in the type system.